# Spring MVC - Redirect inside the Constructor

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-mvc

I would like to know how am I able to redirect the request inside the controller constructor if I need to do it?

For example: Inside the constructor I need to check some condition and if doesn't met I want to redirect to some other place. At the same way the rest of the constructor will not be executed neither the "original following action". I want the code like this.

```
@Controller
class SampleController{
   public SampleController(){
      if(![some condition]){
         ...redirecting code...
      }
      ...rest code...
   }

   ...rest code...
}
```

EDIT

If constructor is not a good option or approach then is there any option like before filter that will execute always before every action of a constructor and will redirect on the failure of some conditions?

Comment: Why are you trying to use constructor for redirection? Shouldn't you be using request handlers?

Comment: There is surely something fishy going on here. Can you please tell more about your use-case and what you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @prashu132 Is it must you want to redirect using constructor?

Comment: @Parvathy yes, i have to check some conditions per controller and then only redirect

Comment: @AdityaJain not much idea about request handlers? can you please refer me a good link that will put some light over it. Or else can you yourself explain me how to use it.

Comment: Looks like the wrong approach for..well..anything. Why would the controllers constructor be responsible to redirect someone somewhere when it's about to handle a request? How would that even work, the bean would have been instanciated a long tome before that..or am I missing something here?

Comment: I do believe you do not know how Spring MVC is supposed to work, and this makes you think in convoluted steps that all seem totally unnecessary. Why not just use a @RequestMapping method? The constructor is the toally wrong approach to do this kind of logic. Or ANY logic.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I do not want to critisize you for not knowing it, it was merely an intro to let you know that your approach is unlikely to be in accordance to what the creators intended. An approach that could work is the suggested answer below, though I have not worked with mvc interceptors myself. I would @RequestMapping methods do this kind of work, because, to me, thats where it belongs. (if a, redirect to x, if b, show view y). Maybe the [spring documentation, chapter 17](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) may be of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an interceptor:

```
public class CheckInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
        if (handler instanceof TheController) {
        // or for any controller: if (handler.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class))
            if (!check()) {
                redirect("/check-failure.html");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }

    private void redirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String path) throws ServletException {
        try {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean check() {
        return ...
    }

}
```

Then register it within the applicationContext.xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="your.package.CheckInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```